# App Crashes Unexpectedly during object mapping using Restkit for IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-data, restkit

I am using restkit 0.10.2 for my app. i have different tables in which data are fetched from Server and stored into DB.

I have three tables One Master Table and two Child Tables. Both Child Table has one-one relationship with Master Table.

[image]

I have two different View Controllers V1 and V2, in which i am calling webservice and mapping data into table Child1 and Child2. Child1, Child2 and Master table has userID as a Primary key.

When i Click on ViewController V1/V2, Following process are executing.

```
1) Getting Data from Server.
2) Delete UserID from Child1/Child2 table(if any), not deleting details in Master Table. Delete Rule is nullify.
3) Map userID to Child1/Child2 Table and Other Details(name, age, userId etc) with Master Table.
```

Mapping Code:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *userDetailMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Master class] inManagedObjectStore:manager.objectStore];
        [userDetailMapping mapKeyPath:@"uid" toAttribute:@"userID"];
        [userDetailMapping mapKeyPath:@"ne" toAttribute:@"name"];
        [userDetailMapping mapKeyPath:@"email" toAttribute:@"email"];
[manager.mappingProvider setMapping:userDetailMapping forKeyPath:@"users"];

        userDetailMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"userID";


RKManagedObjectMapping *userkeyMapping1 = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Child1 class] inManagedObjectStore:manager.objectStore];
        [userkeyMapping1 mapKeyPath:@"uk" toAttribute:@"userID"];
        userkeyMapping1.primaryKeyAttribute = @"userID";
        [manager.mappingProvider setMapping:userkeyMapping1 forKeyPath:@"usk1"];

 RKManagedObjectMapping *userkeyMapping2 = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Child2 class] inManagedObjectStore:manager.objectStore];
        [userkeyMapping2 mapKeyPath:@"uk" toAttribute:@"userID"];
        userkeyMapping2.primaryKeyAttribute = @"userID";
        [manager.mappingProvider setMapping:userkeyMapping2 forKeyPath:@"usk2"];
```

Connecting Relationship

```
[userkeyMapping1 hasOne:@"userDetail" withMapping:userDetailMapping];
        [userkeyMapping1 connectRelationship:@"userDetail" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"userID"];
        [userDetailMapping hasOne:@"userDetail1" withMapping:userkeyMapping1];
        [userDetailMapping connectRelationship:@"userDetail1" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"userID"];


[userkeyMapping2 hasOne:@"userDetail" withMapping:userDetailMapping];
        [userkeyMapping2 connectRelationship:@"userDetail" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"userID"];
        [userDetailMapping hasOne:@"userDetail2" withMapping:userkeyMapping2];
        [userDetailMapping connectRelationship:@"userDetail2" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"userID"];
```

Deleting Object From DB for Child1 and Child2

```
- (void)clearUserKeyTable {
    RKObjectManager *manager = [[RestKit sharedDataManager] objectManager];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [Child1 currentContext];

        NSArray *objects = [Child1 findAll];
        for (Child1 *object in objects) {
            [context deleteObject:object];
        }

        NSError *saveError = nil;
        [context save:&saveError];
        NIDPRINT(@"All records are deleted - %@", saveError);
        for (Child1 *object in objects) {
            [context refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO];
        }
        [context save:&saveError];
        NIDPRINT(@"All records are deleted in Nearby- %@", saveError);
}
```

Note: Both View 1 will refresh automatically in 3 minutes. so fetching and mapping operations will execute irrespective of the screen.

Problem:
Some times when i manually refresh the page in VC1, it will crash. i don't know the exact reason. In My Simulator, it showing as

```
'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x8a5b410 <x-coredata:/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/Child1/p128>.
```

When i debug with my device, it throws a exception, Here is a crash log

```
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/25FD9991-8134-476D-AADE-66D95BFC3C5B/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-02-25 23:17:27.645 -0600
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  10

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3147329e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3233197a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreData                        0x32741b38 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 1472
3   CoreData                        0x327430fa _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 198
4   CoreData                        0x3274ac0c _PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex + 64
5   CoreData                        0x3275532e _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 106
6   CoreData                        0x327497c2 _PF_Handler_Public_SetProperty + 54
7   CoreData                        0x32750a4c -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] + 328
8   CoreData                        0x32751216 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 1286
9   CoreData                        0x3275a82e -[NSManagedObjectContext observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 318
10  Foundation                      0x32fd4eac NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 268
11  Foundation                      0x32fd4b06 NSKeyValueDidChange + 330
12  Foundation                      0x32faeec6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 90
13  CoreData                        0x3274ae26 _PF_ManagedObject_DidChangeValueForKeyIndex + 98
14  CoreData                        0x327553a2 _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 222
15  CoreData                        0x327497c2 _PF_Handler_Public_SetProperty + 54
16  CoreData                        0x32750ad6 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] + 466
17  CoreData                        0x32751216 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 1286
18  CoreData                        0x3275a82e -[NSManagedObjectContext observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 318
19  Foundation                      0x32fd4eac NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 268
20  Foundation                      0x32fd4b06 NSKeyValueDidChange + 330
21  Foundation                      0x32faeec6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 90
22  CoreData                        0x3274ae26 _PF_ManagedObject_DidChangeValueForKeyIndex + 98
23  CoreData                        0x327553a2 _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 222
24  CoreData                        0x327497c2 _PF_Handler_Public_SetProperty + 54
25  CoreData                        0x3274bd1e -[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:] + 86
26  Foundation                      0x32faf71e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 294
27  MyApp                       0x0019aa5c -[RKManagedObjectMappingOperation connectRelationship:] (RKManagedObjectMappingOperation.m:100)
28  MyApp                       0x0019af16 __55-[RKManagedObjectMappingOperation connectRelationships]_block_invoke_0 (RKManagedObjectMappingOperation.m:115)
29  Foundation                      0x32fdc534 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 196
30  Foundation                      0x32fd3db4 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 836
31  MyApp                       0x001b063c -[RKMappingOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] (RKMappingOperationQueue.m:53)
32  MyApp                       0x001b6496 -[RKObjectMapper performMapping] (RKObjectMapper.m:368)
33  MyApp                       0x001b14f0 -[RKObjectLoader mapResponseWithMappingProvider:toObject:inContext:error:] (RKObjectLoader.m:227)
34  MyApp                       0x001b18c2 -[RKObjectLoader performMapping:] (RKObjectLoader.m:271)
35  MyApp                       0x001b1a9e __47-[RKObjectLoader performMappingInDispatchQueue]_block_invoke_0 (RKObjectLoader.m:282)
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x33a6311a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
37  libdispatch.dylib               0x33a62996 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 142
38  libdispatch.dylib               0x33a62890 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 32
39  libdispatch.dylib               0x33a71210 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 188
40  libdispatch.dylib               0x33a713b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
41  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33aa1a0c _pthread_wqthread + 356
42  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33aa18a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Thread 10 Crashed

```
Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: org.restkit.ObjectMapping
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30661350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33aca11e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33b0696e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x314e7d4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x314e4ff4 _ZL17default_terminatev + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32331a74 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x314e5078 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x314e5110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x314e6594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x323319cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreData                        0x32741f60 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 2536
11  CoreData                        0x327430fa _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 198
12  CoreData                        0x3274ac0c _PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex + 64
13  CoreData                        0x3275532e _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 106
14  CoreData                        0x327497c2 _PF_Handler_Public_SetProperty + 54
15  CoreData                        0x32750a4c -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] + 328
16  CoreData                        0x32751216 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 1286
17  CoreData                        0x3275a82e -[NSManagedObjectContext observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 318
18  Foundation                      0x32fd4eac NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 268
19  Foundation                      0x32fd4b06 NSKeyValueDidChange + 330
20  Foundation                      0x32faeec6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 90
21  CoreData                        0x3274ae28 _PF_ManagedObject_DidChangeValueForKeyIndex + 100
22  CoreData                        0x327553a2 _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 222
23  CoreData                        0x327497c2 _PF_Handler_Public_SetProperty + 54
24  CoreData                        0x32750ad6 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] + 466
25  CoreData                        0x32751216 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 1286
26  CoreData                        0x3275a82e -[NSManagedObjectContext observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 318
27  Foundation                      0x32fd4eac NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 268
28  Foundation                      0x32fd4b06 NSKeyValueDidChange + 330
29  Foundation                      0x32faeec6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 90
30  CoreData                        0x3274ae28 _PF_ManagedObject_DidChangeValueForKeyIndex + 100
31  CoreData                        0x327553a2 _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 222
32  CoreData                        0x327497c2 _PF_Handler_Public_SetProperty + 54
33  CoreData                        0x3274bd1e -[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:] + 86
34  Foundation                      0x32faf71e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 294
35  MyApp                       0x0019aa5c -[RKManagedObjectMappingOperation connectRelationship:] (RKManagedObjectMappingOperation.m:100)
36  MyApp                       0x0019af16 __55-[RKManagedObjectMappingOperation connectRelationships]_block_invoke_0 (RKManagedObjectMappingOperation.m:115)
37  Foundation                      0x32fdc536 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 198
38  Foundation                      0x32fd3db4 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 836
39  MyApp                       0x001b063c -[RKMappingOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] (RKMappingOperationQueue.m:53)
40  MyApp                       0x001b6496 -[RKObjectMapper performMapping] (RKObjectMapper.m:368)
41  MyApp                       0x001b14f0 -[RKObjectLoader mapResponseWithMappingProvider:toObject:inContext:error:] (RKObjectLoader.m:227)
42  MyApp                       0x001b18c2 -[RKObjectLoader performMapping:] (RKObjectLoader.m:271)
43  MyApp                       0x001b1a9e __47-[RKObjectLoader performMappingInDispatchQueue]_block_invoke_0 (RKObjectLoader.m:282)
44  libdispatch.dylib               0x33a6311c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
45  libdispatch.dylib               0x33a62996 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 142
46  libdispatch.dylib               0x33a62890 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 32
47  libdispatch.dylib               0x33a71212 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 190
48  libdispatch.dylib               0x33a713b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
49  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33aa1a0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
50  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33aa18a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you accessing core data from multiple threads? You have to be very careful about this, it won't work automatically... There are lots of S.O. questions/answers about that.

Comment: No I am using same thread for accessing and deleting objects

Comment: I found that app crashes on clearUserKeyTable method. But i don;t know the exact pblm

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that you're trying to refresh objects, which are already deleted. The problem causes this piece of code:

```
for (Child1 *object in objects) {
        [context refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO];
    }
[context save:&saveError];
NIDPRINT(@"All records are deleted in Nearby- %@", saveError);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you delete object and refresh it on the same thread. The object had deleted while it trying to refresh this object. Make sure delete objects had been complete before try to refresh.